# Standard Terminology for User's and Producer's Accuracy

Tags: classification, accuracy

In the literature I see terms such as,

1. User's accuracy  Pr( Y = c | X = c);
2. Producer's accuracy  Pr( X = c | Y = c);

where X is the estimator of a particular land use, Y is the random variable associated with the true unobserved land use, and c is a class in a finite set of classes (the support of X and Y).

Now, where I have a bit of confusion is that the User's accuracy and Producer's accuracy above are exact.  But in a large number of papers's, products, and software these quantities are reported as estimates of the above quantities.

Is there standard GIS terminology to separate the parameters (1. and 2.) from the estimates for the parameters?  Such as Actual User's Accuracy?, should the estimates of (1. and 2.) be called the estimated User's and Producer's accuracy respectfully? or is there some other terminology I have missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User and producer accuracies refer to the **actual** value. It is an abuse of language not to mention that the values commonly derived from the confusion matrix are "**estimates of ...**". So you should talk about "estimated user accuracy" if you derive it from sampling (in practice, the indices are always estimated, this is why some people "forget" to mention it). The book from Congalton and Greene is a good reference, and a nice state-ot-the-art review has been written by Olofsson et al (2014): Good Practices for Estimating Area and Assessing Accuracy of Land Change

Remark : I would avoid using "true" before the indices, because it might be associated with the so called "ground truth" (an hypothetical reference dataset without errors)

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the answer to reflect your comment on User's Accuracy.

Comment: +1 Additionally, common statistics derived from the error matrix such as kappa are reported as estimates (e.g. Khat).  I second Congalton and Greene's book as an excellent reference:  `Congalton, R. G., & Green, K. (2008). Assessing the accuracy of remotely sensed data: principles and practices. CRC press.`

Comment: @radouxju switched 'true' with 'actual'; thanks for pointing this out.  I'll also take a look at your reference.